# Python: How can I read floats from a line

Tags: file

I have a VRML file , a part of it is like this:

```
color Color { color [
 .566 .566 1
 .629 .629 1
 .066 .066 1
 .129 .129 1
 .691 .691 1
 .754 .754 1
 .816 .816 1
 .504 .504 1
 .441 .441 1
 .191 .191 1
 1 .879 .879
 .254 .254 1
 1 .754 .754
 1 1 1
 .879 .879 1
 1 .816 .816
 .379 .379 1
 .316 .316 1
 1 .504 .504
 1 .691 .691
 1 .191 .191
 1 .566 .566
 1 .629 .629
 1 .441 .441
 1 .379 .379
 1 .066 .066
 1 .129 .129
 1 0 0
 1 .316 .316
 0 0 1
 1 .254 .254
  ] }
```

I read in line, and put it in a string called 'line'.

How can I extract the three floats from a line?
Thank you.

Comment: `floats = [float(x) for x in line.split()]`

Comment: @TimCastelijns Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the floats from those lines containing three "float-able" strings using:

```
line_floats = [float(field) for field in line.split.()]
```

or for the whole file you can do:

```
def is_three_floats(line):
    fields = line.split()
    if len(fields) != 3: return False
    try:
        line_floats = [float(field) for field in fields]
    except ValueError:
       return False
    return line_floats

float_lines = [is_three_floats(line) for line in fp if is_three_floats(line)]
```

Comment: What good is that function? Calling it twice shouldn't be necessary

Comment: One run tells whether the line can be interpreted as three floats and the other returns the three floats only in the case that the line can indeed be converted to three floats.

Comment: If it really bothers you you can certainly change it to: `float_lines = [[float(f) for f in line.split()] for line in fp if is_three_floats(line)]`